# Issue with implementation layer having different signature than abstraction layer

Tags: c#, abstraction

I've had this design problem for the third time and I have a feeling there is a solution out there that I simply can't figure out. I am not satisfied with the way I solved it previously, so here is where you come in.

Let's say I'm designing a (C#) library that is agnostic in which system it gets used in. So I have the following classes:

```
public interface IAction
{
    void Execute();
}

public class Trigger
{
    private List<IAction> actions;

    public void CheckConditions()
    {
        if (AllConditionsMet())
        {
           ExecuteAllActions();
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteAllActions()
    {
        foreach (IAction action in actions)
        {
            action.Execute();
        }
    }

    protected abstract bool AllConditionsMet();
}

public class BigBulkySystem
{
    private List<Trigger> triggers;

    public void CheckAllTriggers()
    {
        foreach (Trigger trigger in triggers)
        {
            trigger.CheckConditions();
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good. We have a list of triggers in the BigBulkySystem which we check ever so often their conditions. If the conditions are met, the trigger takes care of executing its list of actions.

The issue I'm having now is that I want to implement a layer that is specifically designed for [Unity](https://unity3d.com/). In Unity, you use [coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) in order to be able to wait a few frames before continuing the execution of a method. This is exactly what I'd want for the Trigger.ExecuteAllActions method. I want to wait for each action to finish executing before moving to the next. In order to do that, I would need to have different signatures for the Trigger and IAction. Here is how this would have been in Unity:

```
public interface IAction
{
    IEnumerator Execute();
}

public class Trigger
{
    private List<IAction> actions;

    public void CheckConditions()
    {
        if (AllConditionsMet())
        {
            StartCoroutine(ExecuteAllActions());
        }
     }

    public IEnunmerator ExecuteAllActions()
    {
        foreach (IAction action in actions)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(action.Execute());
        }
    }
 }
```

Notice that a couple of methods now return IEnumerator instead of void, which is the way you define a coroutine in Unity.

Here is an example of a Unity action that moves a player object from position (0,0,0) to (1,1,1) in 5 seconds after a 3 second delay:

```
public class MovePlayerAction : IAction
{
    public GameObject playerObject;

    public IEnumerator Execute()
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(WaitFor(3)); // Wait 3 secs

        float animDuration = 5.0f;
        Vector3 initialPos = Vector3.zero;
        Vector3 finalPos = Vector3.one;
        float t = 0;
        while (t < animDuration)
        {
            playerObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(initialPos, finalPos, t / animDuration); // Lerp between initial and final
            yield return null; // Wait a frame
            t += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitFor(float secs)
    {
        float t = 0;
        while (t < secs)
        {
            yield return null; // Wait a single frame
            t += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

So, my question is: **is there a way to design the system in such a way that I can keep the non-Unity layer free from IEnumerator but also have the Unity layer use them?**

I have a feeling that there is some sort of middle layer, but even so, I couldn't figure out how IAction can have simultaneously `void Execute()` and `IEnumerator Execute()`.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused by `public IEnunmerator ExecuteAllActions()`. Are you really supposed to be returning an IEnumerator over IEnumerators? And what exactly would an implementation of `Execute` be supposed to return as its IEnumerator?

Comment: Yes, it's a little confusing, but that's how coroutines work in Unity. No, you do not return anything. You write an iterator method that Unity takes care of calling during the Update phase. What you see in the example is a coroutine (ExecuteAllActions) that executes other coroutines (each action) in sequence.

Comment: What I mean is if I write an action which implements `IAction` (the Unity version), what should be returned from that class's `Execute` method? It has to return an `IEnumerator`, otherwise it won't compile!

Comment: No, IEnumerator is a very special case in C# where you can define an Iterator Method instead of returning an IEnumerator. I.e.
public class TestAction : IAction { public IEnumerator Execute() { yield null; yield break; } } will work even though it's not returning an IEnumerator. Unless I misunderstood what you where just saying (again). Are you aware of C#'s iterator methods? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/359873/Csharp-Iterator-Pattern-demystified

Comment: I am aware of them (though I usually see them with IEnumerable rather than IEnumerator). So maybe I asked the wrong question. In this case do they only ever `yield break`, or do they yield anything else first?

Comment: The main uses are calling another coroutine by "yield StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine));", waiting a single frame by "yield return null;", exiting a coroutine by "yield break". So, for example, I can wait 3 seconds (by yielding null the appropriate amount) and then move an object over a period of 5 seconds (again, yielding null an appropriate amount of times). Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: @BenAaronson Updated my question with an example to give you an idea.

Comment: Does my answer help? From your edit it looks like you're actually adapting in the other direction from the one I guessed, but the general idea should still be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're consuming a class with a different interface to the one you need, you want the adapter pattern. There are a couple of variations on this, but a simple one for your case would look something like this:

```
public interface IAction
{
    void Execute();
}

public interface IUnityAction
{
    IEnumerator Execute();
}

public class UnityActionAdapter : IUnityAction
{
    private readonly IAction Action;

    public UnityActionAdapter(IAction action)
    {
        Action = action;
    }

    public IEnumerator Execute()
    {
        Action.Execute();
        yield break; //Or whatever you need to yield here
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In your case it looks like you'd be adapting in the other direction, so:

```
public class UnityActionAdapter : IAction
{
    private readonly IUnityAction UnityAction;

    public UnityActionAdapter(IAction unityAction)
    {
        UnityAction = action;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        StartCoroutine(UnityAction.Execute()); //If I'm correctly understanding how you'd execute an action here
    }
}
```

Then you'd have `MovePlayerAction` implement `IUnityAction`, and instead of directly passing a `MovePlayerAction` up to your other layer, you'd wrap it in a `UnityActionAdapter` and pass that along instead.

This is assuming that you actually need to maintain the `IEnumerator` form in an interface in your Unity layer. You might be able to achieve the same thing without the need for adapters by doing something like:

```
public class MovePlayerAction : IAction
{
    public GameObject playerObject;

    private IEnumerator Coroutine()
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(WaitFor(3)); // Wait 3 secs

        float animDuration = 5.0f;
        Vector3 initialPos = Vector3.zero;
        Vector3 finalPos = Vector3.one;
        float t = 0;
        while (t < animDuration)
        {
            playerObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(initialPos, finalPos, t / animDuration); // Lerp between initial and final
            yield return null; // Wait a frame
            t += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Coroutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitFor(float secs)
    {
        float t = 0;
        while (t < secs)
        {
            yield return null; // Wait a single frame
            t += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me where would MovePlayerAction class fit in this design?

Comment: @pek Updated with a couple of options

Comment: Aha! Close, but you are missing one very important part: the Unity Trigger class also has a different signature from the non-Unity Trigger. And that's the trickiest one, because the ExecuteAllActions method really needs to be an Iterator method in order to wait for each action to execute before continuing. Also notice that it calls the IEnumerator Execute method instead of the void Execute method, because otherwise it cannot start a sub-coroutine.

Comment: @pek Create an interface (or abstract base class) for the Trigger too, and inject in a `UnityTrigger` which implements it from the unity layer. If `ExecuteAllActions` needs to be public, then in the Unity version, move the iterator to a private method and have the `ExecuteAllActions` method just start a coroutine, feeding it the iterator method as the parameter.

Comment: @Pek I have to admit this is a pretty weird situation, but I think this general approach will usually serve you well. Key points: 1) Focus on what truly needs to be on the public interface. 2) If that requirement really is completely incompatible between library and consumer, use an adapter. 3) Remember the option of the library exposing an interface and the consumer implementing it then injecting it back to the library.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use Task Parallel Library ?

Sample code of Trigger where I see we can implement this (considering your Non-IEnumerator code):

```
public class Trigger
    {
        private readonly List<Task> TaskActions = new List<Task>();

        public void AddAction(IAction action)
        {
            TaskActions.Add(new Task(()=>{action.Execute();})
        }

        public void CheckConditions()
        {
            if (AllConditionsMet())
            {
                ExecuteAllActions();
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteAllActions()
        {
            foreach(Task task in TaskActions)
            {
                task.Start();
            }
            Task.WaitAll(TaskActions);
        }

        protected abstract bool AllConditionsMet();
    }
```

Regards